# UITableViewController detailView never pushed

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController as one of the view controllers on the second tab of my tab bar controller.

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` i create a detail view controller, but it never gets pushed onto the navigation stack... and the app doesnt crash either, as i can NSLog after the call to `pushViewController`.

This is the method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    KeyboardViewController *v = [[KeyboardViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"KeyboardView" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:v animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"gets here OK"); 
}
```

What would cause this? Surely if navigationController didn't exist then it would crash? Since this is a UITableViewController, it should be created automatically should it not?

Thanks

Comment: Strange... Are you sure everything exists in the way it should?? Try debugging with a breakpoint on that method... So you see what gets allocated and what not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Surely if navigationController didn't exist then it would crash?

No, [nil method] does not crash.

> Since this is a UITableViewController, it should be created automatically should it not?

A UITableViewController does not have a UINavigationController by default. You have to put the UITableViewController inside a UINavigationController.